# How do I create a helper function that can access a private member and operatore += sign?

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, constructor-overloading

My question is at the bottom.

I am creating a module for a Mark to encapsulate between 0 and 100.

I have a few operator and conversion overload functions so far:

```
class Mark {   
      int mark;

   public:

      Mark(); //constructor
      ~Mark(); //deconstructor
      Mark(int value); // mark is created using int value that sets the value of mark

      
      void setEmpty(); // mark = 0
      bool isValid()const; //checks if mark is valid

      //type conversion
      operator int() const; // mark casted to an int. result would be value of the mark or zero if mark is invalid
      operator double() const; //mark casted to a double for gpa..equivalent of int value
      operator char() const; // mark casted to char type...result would be grade latter value of mark

      //binary member operator
      Mark& operator += (int w); // int is added to the value of mark
      Mark& operator = (int i);  // mark is set to an integer
   };
```

This is the main program:

[image]

This is the output:

[image]

**HERE IS MY QUESTION**

I am trying to add mark to an integer and return that integer and any invalid marks would not add any value to the integer. In the main program, this is the code, its the very last 2 lines.

```
Mark n(80), k(120);
cout << (val += n) << endl;
cout << (val += k) << endl;
```

and the output would be

```
140
140
```

I am not able to create this without their being errors saying that my += operator from above is ambiguous. So I am thinking that this needs to be a helper function?

Any help on how to do this?

Comment: Try to make type casting operators `explicit` or, better, replace them with plain member functions like `to_int()` and then write `n.to_int()` instead of `int(n)`.

Comment: Please do not post images of code/output, do copy/paste the actual code/output as text instead

Comment: Alternatively, make your constructor from `int` explicit. And define `Mark & operator+= (Mark const & rhs)`. You can get rid of `Mark & operator= (int n)` if you keep your constructor from `int` implicit.

Comment: @Darhuuk Thanks for replying....couple of questions... if i mark the constructor int as explicit..what will this do? Also can you please explain what you mean by defining the Mark& operator +=(const Mark& rhs) ? the wat I have that one works...just want to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implicit casting is weakening your type. It is so weak, that it has now become ambiguous. Since you allow a Mark to be automatically converted into an `int`, you may as well just use an `int` and create stand-alone functions that manipulate `int`s instead of `Mark`s.

If you insist to manipulate `Mark`s, you should create a type that has a smaller interface that enforces your invariants. I don't know what those are, but let's say that a `Mark` must be an `int` in `[0, 100]`. The following type (class) will ensure that you cannot create a `Mark` with values outside that range. Any accessory functionality is added as a stand-alone function that takes a `Mark` and manipulates its `value` with the confidence that such value will never be outside `[0,100]`, because it is impossible for it to be outside the range.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class Mark {
 public:
  Mark(int value = 0) {
    validate(value);
    m_value = value;
  }

  int value() const { return m_value; }

  void clear() { m_value = 0; }

  // I don't know why you need in-place modifications, but here they are and
  // they are exception safe.

  Mark& operator+=(const Mark& other) {
    int new_value = value() + other.value();
    validate(new_value);
    m_value = new_value;
    return *this;
  }

  Mark& operator-=(const Mark& other) {
    int new_value = value() - other.value();
    validate(new_value);
    m_value = new_value;
    return *this;
  }

 private:
  void validate(int value) const {
    // place your own logic here -- the purpose is to ensure that a Mark cannot
    // exist unless it is in a valid state.
    if (value < 0 || value > 100) {
      throw std::runtime_error("value must be in [0, 100]");
    }
  }

  int m_value = 0;
};

double to_double(const Mark& mark) {
  // replace with your own logic
  return mark.value() / 100.0;
}

char to_char(const Mark& mark) {
  // replace with your own logic
  if (mark.value() > 0 && mark.value() < 50) {
    return 'D';
  } else if (mark.value() >= 50 && mark.value() <= 100) {
    return 'A';
  } else {
    return 'X';
  }
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Mark& m) {
  // replace with your own logic
  return os << "Mark(" << m.value() << ") / " << to_double(m) << " / "
            << to_char(m);
}

int main() {
  Mark m;
  Mark n(25);
  Mark k(100);
  // Mark p(-10); // uncommented will throw exception
  std::cout << m << "\n"
            << n << "\n"
            << k << "\n"
      // << p << "\n" // uncommented will throw exception
      ;
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ clang++ example.cpp -std=c++2a
$ ./a.out                             
Mark(0) / 0 / X
Mark(25) / 0.25 / D
Mark(100) / 1 / A
```